# android smartfon as a loudspeaker for my dektop pc

Tags: multimedia

I want to use my android smartfon as a loudspeaker for my dektop pc
I found this instruction ( Install SoundWire in Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish) in the net.

unfortunately, the soundwireserver isn starting out of the folder. Can anybody help me out here?

Comment: Hello. What is the link to this instruction? Unless we can see the instructions and the version of Ubuntu being used it is unlikely anyone can.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 has been out of support for several years now. I hope you're running a more recent version ...

Comment: http://electronics4ubeginners.blogspot.com/2019/02/blog-post.html

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic on this site (refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). Being EOL, mirrors can drop the release, and the main archive moves to old-releases.  Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/07/19/ubuntu-18-10-cosmic-cuttlefish-end-of-life-reached-on-july-18-2019/

Comment: If you're using a *i386* install, you could have forced your machine to 19.04 for a further 9 months of *patches* & security fixes, however all *i386* support ended with Ubuntu 19.04 (the successor to Ubuntu 18.10 which was the last release with full *i386* support; it was only available for 19.04 via pre-release ISOs.  Thus if you kept using 18.10 because it was the last support with *i386* - you should return to the prior 18.04 release which was a LTS.  If you're using another architecture - you'll need to backup & re-install and upgrade paths are now well gone.